# The Best Recovery Model to Rebuilt Indexes

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for some  advice. I have to rebuild my database indexes (because of shrinking) but due to having low disk space, I am not sure which recovery model is better to avoid getting disk space shortage error in order of increasing log file's size. Please help me choose between simple or bulk log recovery model.

Comment: How big is your database, exactly? If you're running out of disk-space can't you get a cheap 1TB SSD from Amazon next-day to hold you-over?

Comment: Switch to `SIMPLE` recovery before rebuilding, then switch back afterwards to `FULL` (don't forget to take a full backup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shrinking is a wasteful operation.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/). [Index maintenance such as index rebuilds are also a wasteful operation.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/index-maintenance-madness/). Rebuilding your indexes will generate a lot of unused allocated space in the data file. Index fragmentation is pretty meaningless in regards to performance. As you've seen, shrinking your database causes high levels of index fragmentation. It's a vicious cycle, like Brent mentions in the first article I linked. My advice, don't do either (except for very rare circumstances).

But if you still are hung up on rebuilding your indexes, then doing so with Simple Recovery Model will at least minimize the logging in your Transaction Log on the process. It won't save you any space in the data file though. The catch is by switching to Simple Recovery Model, you lose point in time recovery after the last Full backup, and so are at risk for data loss until your next Full backup. You won't be able to utilize point in time recovery until you switch back to Full Recovery Model and then take a Full backup too. If your recovery point objectives can tolerate that, then that's fine.

Comment: "or until you switch back to Full Recovery Model" no you need to both switch to full recovery *and* take a full backup, or the log chain will still be broken.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, agreed. That's a little bit of a confusing sentence. I moreso meant they're at risk until their next Full backup which then is the latest copy of the data for just that very moment, but agreed they'll then be at risk again shortly after without switching back to Full Recovery Model. Hopefully clarified that sentence in my latest update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple features you can use for rebuilding your indexes that may help your cause.

If you have your TEMPDB on a dedicated disk, you could try running the index rebuild utilizing the TEMPDB. Additionally, you can work your way from small to big by limiting the number of pages when running index optimization.

You could use OLA hallengren's jobs for this.
https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

When using OLA Hallengren, I would then also recommend to update the statistics seperately. As for the recovery model, I'm not sure if it matters.

I believe the general concensus with regards to fragmentation, above 5% it is recommended to reorganize and above 30% you should rebuild.

Comment: "*the general concensus with regards to fragmentation, above 5% it is recommended to reorganize and above 30% you should rebuild*" - eh, that's an outdated Microsoft recommendation. I'd say the general consensus is index maintenance is a wasteful operation for little to no gain.

Comment: @J.D. The article from Brent Ozar you refer to isn't very specific regarding use cases and neither is it very scientific. I would argue that with plenty of time with regards to maintenance windows, performing indexoptimize more regularly will keep things from possibly performing poorly. It will also make sure your indexoptimze job won't take too long. In my opinion just a piece of pro active maintenance. As for the fragmentation percentage, is Microsoft's recommendation actually outdated and have they themselves adjusted their recommendation? This article isn't enough to suggest that.

Comment: Brent Ozar is a well regarded and knowledgeable person in the SQL Server community, as well as the other contributors to that site (Tara, Erik etc). I've heard recent recommendations from other knowledgeable Microsoft staff agree index maintainence doesn't help performance. I've witnessed it first hand too from working with terabyte big tables in the 10s of billions of rows, that were heavily transactional - index maintenance was pointless for performance. There's plenty of other articles out there regarding index maintenance providing little gain (among bad or outdated information - careful).

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree that Brent and his team have invaluable contributions within this community. I'm just saying its use case dependent. So I get where you're coming from and agree it might not always be useful to optimize indexes. I personally think in my use cases its the safer bet though.

Comment: Eh, I've only seen one use case where it actually helped and that was for a poorly designed database system to begin with (all tables with no clustered indexes and GUID primary keys). So it was a bandaid instead of a fix to the root problem in that case. Otherwise any other benefits are likely the byproduct of other actions that occur when an index rebuild occurs such as updated statistics (but one can achieve this without an index rebuild). So it's a wasteful operation in regards to server resources. Sure if your server has nothing better to do than no harm no foul, but also not necessary.

Comment: Also please note this is all in regards to rowstore index maintenance. There is a type of columnstore index maintenance that *may* be useful periodically, when using columnstore indexes. But columnstore is a different ballgame.

Comment: @J.D. To be fair, a lot of the times suppliers of applications have poorly designed databases. But I catch your drift.